# Make the dialog used to decline flags draggable

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, popups

The dialog box used from moderators to decline a flag is not draggable. Since the dialog box to close-vote a question is draggable, also this one should be draggable.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Hey isn't that top secret information? ;-)

Comment: I thought the secret information was that control-K pressed tree times makes the dialog box appear also for who is not moderator. Whoops… Do tell me I just wrote a comment you only see. `;)`

Comment: Wasn't it ALT+F4 pressed twice? :D

Comment: That is if you are using Windows, it's Friday night, there isn't a full moon, and a bunch of other conditions are met; in all the other cases, control-K works. `;)`

Comment: As a non-moderator, I would love this feature.